# Undefined returned when object method called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create an object in the Chrome console with a function to increase the age.  When I try and increase the age, I get "undefined" but I'm not sure why.
Below is what I type into the console.  As you can see the last line says undefined but it should say 41.  Any thoughts?

```
>>obj = {}
Object {}
>>obj.firstName='John'
"John"
>>obj.lastName='Soro'
"Soro"
>>obj.age=40
40
>>obj.increaseAge = function() {
this.age++;
}
function () {
this.age++;
}
>>obj.lastName
"Soro"
>>obj.firstName
"John"
obj.increaseAge
function () {
this.age++;
}
obj.increaseAge()
undefined
```

Comment: This is the _return value_ of the function. In JavaScript all functions return `undefined` by default unless you have an explicit `return` statement.

Comment: How do I get the method to work and return 41

Comment: @Isaac You must `return`: `obj.increaseAge = function() { return this.age++; }`

Comment: @Oriol - I think you mean: `obj.increaseAge = function() { return ++this.age; }`